# INNER JOIN in django orm

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have two tables that only contain the same product ids and they didnt have foreigh keys. So question is about how i can filter them both in query by id.
In SQL i want to do something like this

```
SELECT Url FROM pricehistory p INNER JOIN product d ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
```

Models look like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   ProductID = models.CharField(..)
   Price = models.FloatField(..)
   Url = models.CharField(..)
   ....

class PriceHistory(models.Model):
  ProductID = models.CharField(..)
  Price = models.FloatField(..)
  Retailer = models.CharField(..)
  Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(..)
```

Comment: please share your models.

Comment: here is it.....

Comment: Is the ProductID on the Product model the primary key? Why is the ProductID column on PriceHistory not defined as a ForeignKey to the Product model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`Exists(…)`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Product.objects.filter(
    Exists(PriceHistory.objects.filter(ProductID=OuterRef('ProductID')))
).values('Url')
```

This will not perform an `INNER JOIN`, but will make an `WHERE EXISTS (…)` subquery that will only retain the `Url`s of the `Product`s which have a `PriceHistory`.

I would advise to turn the `ProductID` in a `ForeignKey` that refers to the `ProductID` of the `Product`, so:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ProductID = models.CharField(unique=True)
    # …

class PriceHistory(models.Model):
    ProductID = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        to_field='ProductID',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='ProductID'
    )
  # …
```

This will store the `ProductID` of the `Product` in the database but also guarantee referential integrity, and makes it more convenient to make queries with the Django ORM.